# How to access app specific iphone files in 2020?

Tags: iphone, ios

I've seen some posts on this, but they are ancient and none of the answers are relevant anymore. Ex: The app functionality in iTunes is long gone.

Is there still a way to access a specific app's files on an iPhone *without* jailbreaking that iPhone?

In my case, I'm trying to get to the Kindle files so that I can download some traditional Chinese books. You can't download them using the Kindle for desktop app because it doesn't support the traditional Chinese fonts (which boggles my brain to no end considering it is the primary writing system for some 30 million people and it's a couple of lines of code to fix).

Comment: Can you use iCloud for this? iPhone can sync some kinds of files with iCloud.

Comment: Na, unfortunately I gave that a shot. Same problem. Brilliant programming in action 

Comment: Which version of macOS are you running?